# What is the code to display an integer value in the xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, int

I want to display an integer that the user will define in the XML.

```
    TextView Years = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Years);
    Years.setText(Age);
```

I know that this is right, but I don't know what to put in the XML to have the integer displayed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put strings in xml. And if you want to use that string as an integer. You use the line

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
```

Comment: Is there anything that has to go into the values file under strings? And what do you put in the XML? I cannot get the code to set the R file with the new string.

Comment: Are you mentioning the strings.xml in the values folder? If not put your xml up. textview can take resource id Years.setText(R.string.yourtext);

Comment: Yes I am, but I also cannot get the R file to have the string in it.